# allocVector() in C and System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory?

Tags: c#, c++, c, r

I have a problem with the allocVector() function. I wrote a code (DLL) in C that can be called in R. I would like to call a method of that DLL into my application in C#. The DLL code works fine but when the compiler reaches the next line ROut = allocVector(INTSXP, 2*3)
It gives following exception:
Unhandled exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
The code is as follow:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <R_ext/Applic.h>
#include <R_ext/Lapack.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    void castType(int *result)
    {
        SEXP ROut;
        ROut = allocVector(INTSXP, 2*3)
        ROut = PROTECT(ROut);
        int *clustOut = INTEGER(ROut); 
        result= clustOut ; 
    } 
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick read, I think you use the value 6 as the value of the pointer. There are other things in there that are problematic.

Stepping back, I suggest a couple of things for your C#/C interop:

- If you do not have a lot of existing C code of your own in this API, I'd suggest you port it to C# and use R.NET ([NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/R.NET.Community), [source code](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet))
- If you do have a substantial amount of C/C++ code, or absolutely need a C layer, you can have a look at this [sample code](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet-support/tree/master/wrapcppdll). I put that together to test a couple of things before answering, so I may as well commit the source.

For the sake of other readers, the crux of it elaborated from the function in the question is:

C API:

```
void c_api_call(int * result)
{
    SEXP p = some_R_calculations();
    int* int_ptr = INTEGER_POINTER(p);
    int n = length(p);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result[i] = int_ptr[i];
    // We are done with p; irrespective of where some_R_calculations got it, 
    // we can notify the R GC that this function releases it.
    R_ReleaseObject(p);
}
```

C# interop wrapper:

```
public class CppInterop : DynamicInterop.UnmanagedDll // http://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicInterop/
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate void _c_api_call([In, Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] values);

    public int[] CreateArray()
    {
        // These two following references could be cached for efficiency later on.
        var getLength = this.GetFunction<_c_api_call_getlength>("c_api_call_getlength");
        var getValues = this.GetFunction<_c_api_call>("c_api_call");

        // As far as I know it is preferable, if not needed, to handle arrays in two steps:
        // we need to know the expected length to allocate in C# buffer memory.
        int expectedLength = getLength();
        int[] result = new int[expectedLength];
        getValues(result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed the approach to use rClr  in your code but I encountered the following error when compiling:

Comment: error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Rdll.lib' C:\Users\Stephan\Documents\GitHub\rdotnet-support\wrapcppdll\mycpp\LINK mycpp

Comment: I followed the following steps as they are called on the site codeplex to build rClr on my system:
%R% CMD check rClr
%R% CMD REMOVE rClr
%R% CMD INSTALL rClr
And I received the message Build succeeded.

Comment: but I do not know why I always get the error message: cannot open file 'Rdll.lib'
I have another question about R.NET: Is it possible to call a function of R through some specific packages, such as 'rrcov'?. I would be thankful if you refer me to some materials.
Thanks in advance,